# Fast insert of Matlab array element one at a time

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to speed up a main bottleneck in my code. It is the insertion of an array element into the middle of an array. These elements must be inserted one at a time, as I do not know them in advance.  I cannot collect them and insert them all at once because the elements that come later (and their insertion positions) depend on the updated array in a ccomplicated way.

I surmise that the speed limitation is due to 2 factors: (1) the fact that the vector is grown one element at a time, and (2) the copying of all elements that need to be bumped to the right when an element is inserted.  Factor #2 is a bit simplified, since I suspect that the entire updated vector is assembled in its entirety when a new element is inserted.  I don't think I have a solution to address factor #2, but I did experiment with a few possibilities for factor #1 -- namely, pre-allocation.

The following tests show that my current method (no pre-allocation) cannot be improved upon with the alternative approaches that I tried.  The test iteratively inserts new elements into position 2 of an array using an inner loop.  The out loop simply re-performs this test a 100 times for better timing stats.

```
clc; Ntests=1e4;

disp('1) Pre-allocate, update vector in-place without creating new array.')
tic
for j = 1 : Ntests
   clear a
   a(100) = 0;
   a(1)=1;
   for i = 2:100
      a(3:end) = a(2:99);
      a(2) = i;
   end % i
end % j
toc

disp('2) Pre-allocate, copy & create new array by concatenation.')
tic
for j = 1 : Ntests
   clear a
   a(100) = 0;
   a(1)=1;
   for i = 2:100
      a = [ a(1) i a(2:end-1) ];
   end % i
end % j
toc

disp('3) No pre-allocation (current method).')
tic
for j = 1 : Ntests
   clear a
   a(1)=1;
   for i = 2:100
      a = [ a(1) i a(2:end) ];
   end % i
end % j
toc
```

The results are:

```
1) Pre-allocate, update vector in-place without creating new array.
Elapsed time is 2.359021 seconds.
2) Pre-allocate, copy & create new array by concatenation.
Elapsed time is 4.221047 seconds.
3) No pre-allocation (current method).
Elapsed time is 2.248106 seconds.
```

Is the situation really as dismal as this, or is there something further that I can do about the bottleneck?

**Context of the problem:**

Each double array represents a timeline for a machine, and the doubles are start times of periods of usage.  The end times are stored in another double array.  For each period of usage, there are other fields besides start time and end time.  So I have a handful of arrays, one per field.

When I get a new demand for a period of usage, it is in the form of a collection of values, one per field, and I have to see if it fits into the timeline (I have other logic to determine that, which I'm also in the midst of trying to speed up).  If it doesn't fit, I go to another timeline and try again.  If no existing timelines can accommodate the start-to-end times for the new demand, I create another machine with a blank timeline.

Say that a period of usage consists of N fields, with start and end times being two of these fields. Each timeline is represented as N arrays rather than a struct array of N fields.  This is because empirical testing and web surfing indicates that N arrays of scalars are faster to manipulate than a single struct array of N fields.  However, if I have to update N arrays of scalars just to insert one period of usage, this may no longer be true, and I have yet to test this.  (I revamped the code in moving from struct array to struct with array fields, and it will take some time to go backward).

The above code is only meant to test the overhead of inserting into the middle an array.  It isn't meant to emulate the whole problem described in this Context section.

Note that I agreed in the comments below that this is a priority queue problem.  This is assuming the each new usage period was already determined by my other logic to fit into the timeline, and then treating the start time as the priority.  Upon reflection, however, it's not really a full priority queue problem in that I don't actually pull anything out of the queue until the very end. So it's a simplified use of a priority queue to build up a timeline.

While I have yet to select and incorporate openly available Matlab code for priority queues, I am less than 50% confident that there will be a net speedup.  This is because calling out to functions is slow in Matlab, and each timeline on average contains less than half a dozen periods of usage when it is entirely built up (at least for the current problem set).  So it is quite possible that simple insertion may be the fastest possible way to build up a timeline compared to calling out to a function to update a priority queue.  I'll update this question when I have had a chance to try it.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you're using wrong data structure for that? What about priority queue and inserting an element with a priority and after you're finished map the queue to array list? I'm sure there are many implementations of priority queue in matlab.

Comment: I think your example has been simplified too much to provide meaningful suggestions. It's hard to know what you really intend when you're simply clearing the existing array and then overwriting all of its values 100 times.

Comment: @kostek: A priority queue is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll look into implementations. Hopefully, they can improve on the fundamental limitation.  Thank you.

Comment: @beaker: I added a clarification to the paragraph preceding the code.  The outer loop that clears the variable a 100 times is simply to re-perform the test 100 times for better timing stats. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That still doesn't explain what you're actually trying to do; the three code snippets don't even produce the same results. The first one gives `a = [1 100 100:-1:3]`, the second one gives `a = [1 100:-1:2]` and the third gives `a = [1 100]`.

Comment: @user36800: Please describe what your data structure is supposed to do fast. While someone find a better way for inserting (Queue, Linked list etc), such a data structure might slow down your other processing steps which read the data structure.

Comment: @beaker: You're right, I was treating the code as trivial and didn't check the actual content of the arrays (I was only trying to emulate the time overhead of insertion). Corrected now, and thanks for patiently pointing that out.

Comment: @Daniel: Done.  Thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: Add each new element to the end of the (pre-allocated) arrays and use a separate array of indices to indicate sorted position.

Comment: I would switch this to  use objects instead of naked arrays.  If you configure an object for each machine and check it's timeline you can preallocate the timeline for each machine.  A simple function can be written to check if the request could fit a machine.  Then create an array of machines.

Comment: @beaker: That is an excellent idea!  I must try it, perhaps some time today, but if not, then in about one week's time.  Unfortunately, I guess like most people, I'm having to interleave huge hunks of technical work with non-technical work.  But I appreciate the very simple & elegant solution (which I no doubt is obvious amongst Comp Sci folks).

Comment: Let us know how it works :)

Comment: @Matt: I already uses classes for various data structures, but I am cognizant of the overhead of making method/function calls.  I'll certainly keep that in mind (classes were never a sticky point for me when I coded in C++ a decade ago, but I'm careful about the speed overhead in Matlab).  I'll first try beaker's suggestion of appending to a pre-allocated array and using index arrays to track the sorted position.

Comment: Actually, I mentally went down the train of thought of using indices (or as I like to think of them, pointers) to track newly appended items on the timeline. It occurred to me that I actually went down that conceptual path early on. The reason why I stopped was that it doesn't seem to solve the problem, that of inserting a new element in the middle of an array. If I used pointers, I would simply be inserting new pointers into a pointer array rather than doubles, as I do now.

Comment: I could use linked lists, but with Matlab's speed penalty for control flow code (as opposed to vectorized code), I highly doubt that it would help, especially with the short arrays that I'm dealing with.

Does that assessment seem reasonable, or am I misunderstanding/missing something?

Comment: I can see were maintaining an array of pointers can help if I have more than just a few fields per usage period, but as of now, I've forgone the use of all fields except for two (usage period start and end times).